# how import CSV into neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am very new in Neo4j. I downloaded neo4j 1.9 for windows. And I tried to run the code in Gremlins in order to import CSV files into Neo4j. I saved CSV files (One of them includes nodes and another one contains relationships) into a new folder, named target, in graph.db. Then I executed this line:

```
java -server -Xmx4G -jar ../batch-import/target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar neo4j/data/graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv
```

But I got this error:

startup failed

```
==> groovysh_parse: 51: expecting EOF, found 'target' @ line 51, column 42.
==>    r -Xmx4G -jar ../batch-import/target/bat
==>                                  ^
==>
```

I got the same error when I ran this:

```
"git clone git://github.com/jexp/batch-import.git"
```

When i wanted to install maven via this code:

```
 "sudo apt-get install maven2"
```

I got this error:

```
No such property: apt for class: groovysh evaluate.
```

I will be appreciated, if help me to import csv Files into Neo4j.
Thanks
Fatemeh

Comment: on windows, maybe you could try import the batch via gremlin's command importGraphML - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph . just try to create the proper graphml xml file instead of your csvs.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation https://github.com/jexp/batch-import focusses on Mac and Linux system. When running on Windoze, you need to convert all unix path seperators ("/") into the windows equivalent ("\").

Also the apt-get command is Linux specific.

For a very basic description on how to import csv data into neo4j, check out http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/01/fun-with-beer-and-graphs.html.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I checked this website already. It seems Gephi works with Neo4j 1.5 while I am working with Neo4j 1.9.

Comment: @FatemehHosseinzadeh that should not be a problem, since the data export format is the same no matter which version of gephi/neo4j you use.

Comment: Thanks Ulkas, but Neo4j export is not active (the color is gray), and i think because I don't have Neo4j 1.5. Moreover, when I searched to figure out the reason, I found some comments that said Gephi works with Neo4j 1.5 not Neo4j 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you have java installed, you can also download a ready-made jar from: 
https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/downloads

Don't execute it from the gremlin shell but your normal commandline (Windows - Run - cmd)

You can also just click the "download as zip" button for the github repository to get the code.

For Maven download and unzip apache maven from: http://maven.apache.org

Comment: Thanks Michael, I created a graphMl and load it in Neo4j. However, I am going to try your method too.